# Is there a way to display text values over actual inside value in a Combobox in Python with ttk?

Tags: python, combobox, localization, ttk

Currently, I know we can put values as following, and the selected display value will be stored in the variable given in `textvariable`.

```py
ttk.Combobox(parent,
             ...
             textvariable=ttk_variable,
             values=['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
             ...)
```

I'm looking for something that can translate the values we see into some internal values.

```py
ttk.Combobox(parent,
             ...
             textvariable=ttk_variable,
             values=['text1', 'text2', 'text3'],
             ...)
```

And when we select `'text1'`, what we get in value in `ttk_variable` will be `value1`, and so on. I'd like to make it possible to set text in different languages, to enable localization in other words.

Does that thing exist with `ttk.Combobox`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try configuring the values option of the Combobox with a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the display text and the actual value.
Example:

```
values = [
    ("text1", "value1"),
    ("text2", "value2"),
    ("text3", "value3"),
]
```

EDIT:

```
val = {
    "text1": "value1",
    "text2": "value2",
    "text3": "value3"
}

def show_value(event):
   selected_index = combo.current()
   selected_value = combo['values'][selected_index]
   ttk_variable.set(val[selected_value])
   print(ttk_variable.get())

...

ttk_variable = StringVar()
combo = ttk.Combobox(
    ...
    values=list(val.keys())
    ...
)
combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", show_value)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer!

I just tried that out and what it does, unless I do it wrong, is displaying both the display text and the internal value at the same time.

So in this case, it displays `text1 value1` for the first option, and the same thing gets stored in the variable when it is selected.

Comment: So I don't know if tkinter can do the mapping you suggest. I made an edit to the previous answer with a way to do it manually using dictionaries.